# Confusion around Lambert's Cosine Law in Ray Tracing in One Weekend

Tags: raytracing, mathematics, diffuse

Peter Shirely's *Ray Tracing in One Weekend* presents the following function to calculate the color of a lambertian material (See chapter's 7 and 8):

```cpp
bool lambertian::scatter(ray ray_in, hit_record rec, vec3& attenuation, ray &scattered) {
  vec3 target = rec.p + rec.normal + random_in_unit_sphere();
  scattered = ray(rec.p, target - rec.p);
  attenuation = this->albedo;
  return true;
}
```

I've read through other material that mentions Lambert's Cosine Law when discussing diffuse materials. Why is the `cos` term omitted from Peter Shirely's text? Is it canceled out somehow? My expectation is that the attenuation term should look something like:

```cpp
  attenuation = this->albedo * dot(rec.normal, ray_in.direction);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is cancelled out by the probability density function in the estimator. The pdf in their case is exactly: $\frac{\cos\theta}{\pi}$, which is in the denominator: `att = albedo * cos_theta / pdf = albedo * pi`. They have absorbed pi in the albedo. Note that there's an update on github to the code, since `random_in_unit_sphere()` actually generates a $\cos^3\theta$ distribution, they fixed it to `random_on_unit_sphere()` which generates a $\cos\theta$ distribution. So technically you are working with a $\cos^2\theta$ brdf here and not constant.